# How can I update 2 different columns with different data in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having trouble figuring this out : I have a column in my table called "active" and it is a boolean. Now when I set one row to active=1, I want the previous one to be set to active=0. How can I achieve that?

That's my code for now, what do I have to add? Thanks!

```
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=1 WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";
```

EDIT (full code) :

```
<?php
    include 'a_head.php';
    include '../sql.php';

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM messages WHERE active=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $prv = $row["id"];
        }}

    $sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=0 WHERE active=".$prv."";
    $sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=1 WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Message set <br /><a href=\"/\"><button>Back</button></a>";
    } else {
        echo "Could not update message.";
    }

                    $conn->close();
    include 'a_foot.php';
?>
```

Comment: How is "previous one" determined?

Comment: You can subtract one from the current id:
`$prev_id = $_GET['id'] - 1;`
`$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=0 WHERE id=".$prev_id."";`
`$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=1 WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";`

Comment: You're leaving yourself open to an SQL injection. If the GET array will always be an integer, use `(int)` if you're not already doing so, or a prepared statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to work with the new update on requirements...

If you run the "active to 0" script first then you should only have one value to update?

```
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=0 WHERE active=1";
```

Then we can run your original script to mark the new id as active

```
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=1 WHERE id=".$id."";
```

**EDIT**
In that case we should find the id of the active row first

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM messages WHERE active=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $prv = $row["id"];
    }}
```

Then apply that id to the sql

```
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=0 WHERE active=".$prv."";
```

Followed by your original update

```
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET active=1 WHERE id=".$id."";
```

Comment: This leaves them open to an SQL injection.

Comment: You're assuming that $id is coming from user input?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it's user input or `href` or whatever, it's still open to injection.

Comment: This is the "admin" part of the website and it is secured with an .htaccess and it's just a small intranet website so SQL Injection isn't really an issue for the moment, I'll secure it later. But anyways, I tried what @Simon said and it just sets another row to active=1 without changing the old one..

Comment: That's reassuring, I did write the above with the assumption of "trust" (can be lethal I know) but as this is not public facing the above should do the trick so long as no malicious intent is introduced.

Comment: Still does the same thing for some reason.. I've edited my post with the full code of the page, perhaps there's something wrong elsewhere?

Comment: You need to execute the first query before you reset $sql otherwise it will just override your first script.

Comment: Works now! Thanks!

Comment: I don't care who it is intended for, it should always protect not only against malicious intent but possible unintentional introduction of bad information.